# How to compile MethodCallExpression with operations on arguments?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I have a method Method

```
private static int Method(int n)
{
    return n;
}
```

I get MethodCallExpression in overrided VisitMethodCall in my ExpressionVisitor. MethodCallExpression contains:

```
n => Method(2 + n)
```

I want to compile it to Func and call like this:

```
func(3)
```

And it's should return 5.

I tried this:

```
    IEnumerable<ParameterExpression> parameters = expression.Arguments.Select(a => Expression.Parameter(a.Type, a.ToString()));
    MethodCallExpression call = Expression.Call(expression.Method, parameters);
    Expression<Func<Int32, Int32>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(call, call.Arguments.OfType<ParameterExpression>());
    var func = lambda.Compile();
    Console.WriteLine(func(3));
```

And it's return me 3, not 5

It is because 2+x it is param name and I replace it with 3.

Comment: Why would you want to do something like that in override of expression visitor?

Comment: it's just education example, I will send this functions to outside of visitor

Comment: I think you will need another expression visitor for that. You need to extract\replace parameters (not arguments) from that MethodCallExpression.

Comment: I was researched it, but it's not contains any info about binary operation

Comment: For binary operations you can use the Expression.MakeBinary factory or just use the specific one which is Expression.Add. Please see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you would ever do this, but anyway to do this you need to extract parameters (not arguments) used by your `MethodCallExpression`. For that you can abuse expression visitor like this:

```
public class ParametersExtractorVisitor : ExpressionVisitor {
    public IList<ParameterExpression> ExtractedParameters { get; } = new List<ParameterExpression>();
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node) {
        ExtractedParameters.Add(node);
        return base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

Then use it like this in your code:

```
var visitor = new ParametersExtractorVisitor();
visitor.Visit(expression);
MethodCallExpression call = Expression.Call(expression.Method, expression.Arguments);
Expression<Func<Int32, Int32>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(call, visitor.ExtractedParameters);
var func = lambda.Compile();
Console.WriteLine(func(3));
```

Comment: I understood! I was close, damn! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a visitor to implement it.
Basically your `Method` function should be supplied with the result of an addition operation of the value passed to the lambda with the constant value of 2.

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var method = typeof(Program).GetMethod("Method", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "n");
            var add = Expression.Add(Expression.Constant(2, typeof(int)), parameter);
            var methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(null, method, add);
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(methodCallExpression, parameter);
            var func = lambda.Compile();

            Console.WriteLine(func(3));
        }

        public static int Method(int n) => n;
    }
}
```

I would implement it using the visitor by mutating the MethodCallExpression

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Test
{

    class MethodCallVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly int toAdd;

        public MethodCallVisitor(int toAdd) {
            this.toAdd = toAdd;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node) {
            var add = Expression.Add(node.Arguments.First(), Expression.Constant(toAdd));

            return Expression.Call(node.Object, node.Method, add);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var methodCallVisitor = new MethodCallVisitor(2);
            var method = typeof(Program).GetMethod("Method", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "n");
            var methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(null, method, parameter);
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(methodCallExpression, parameter);

            lambda = (Expression<Func<int, int>>)methodCallVisitor.Visit(lambda);
            var func = lambda.Compile();

            Console.WriteLine(func(3));
        }

        public static int Method(int n) => n;
    }
}
```

Comment: I need, because my goal is replace one methods to another methods for print on console time of starting of this methods

Comment: OP has only MethodCallExpression which is part of larger expression tree. He wants to make a lambda with this method call only, as far as I understood.